# msbuild: run a task before tests

Tags: c#, msbuild

hello I'm currently looking forward to generate a docker container that contains all my migrations.

however I wanted to look into msbuild to only build the container once for all test-csproj's. so I tried to somehow add a `Directory.Build.props` or a `Directory.Build.target` and searched for tasks that I can hook into that are after compilation but before running the tests but I could not find anything.

I tried something like:

```
  <Target Name="DebugTests" BeforeTargets="VSTestTask"> <!-- or VSTest -->
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running before Tests />
  </Target>
```

unfortunatly it does not run. is there any way to accomplish this?

actually I can use:

```
  <Target Name="DebugTest" BeforeTargets="RunTests;VSTest">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="running before tests" />
  </Target>
```

unfortunatly it will run for each tests project, is there a way to make it run once for the whole solution?

Comment: I had another task with the same requirement cannot find a solution. I suggest to use your second variant (which is running before each test project) and accomplish the 'singleton' execution inside the task itself. I mean create the image only if it isn't exist already.

Comment: There is a way to [customize the solution build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-solution-build?view=vs-2022) but it only works from the command line and not when building the solution from Visual Studio. An approach that will work for VStudio and cmd is to create a 'utility' project that creates the container and, in the solution, set the test projects to have "build dependencies" on the utility project. See [`Microsoft.Build.NoTargets`](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks#microsoftbuildnotargets) for a project SDK type for utility projects.

Comment: If you want to share a common target in a `Directory.Build.*` file (instead of needing to always build from the solution file), you will need to have a mechanism to detect if the work is already done or not. You might choose a file to be a sentinel file. If the sentinel file either doesn't exist or is older than the 'input' file(s), then the work needs to be done. For commands that don't create output files, when the command is successful create or touch a file that exists only to be the sentinel.

Comment: I assume someone has customized your project(s) to run tests. Running tests is not part of the "build". Instead of a utility project to create the container, consider a utility project that depends on the test projects, collects the test assemblies and test-target assemblies, creates the container, and runs the tests.